# In Visual Studio with C#, how do I make the () appear automatically when I type, such as .Focus()?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

In Visusal Studio 2010 Express when I type the following:

```
txtUsername.Fo
```

and then hit enter, it just creates the following with Intellisense:

```
txtUsername.Focus
```

What I want it to do it do the following:

```
txtUsername.Focus()
```

Is there a way to make Intellisense auto-add the () as the end of functions for me?

Comment: try hitting the TAB key Twice.. i know it works for method templates

Answer (score 3):

I don't think Visual Studio has this option.
Somewhat related - in some scenarios, <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> will automatically insert a snippet.
for example, `if` + <kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> gives you:

```
if (|)
{

}
else
{

}
```

However, I absolutely love [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) and completely recommend it.
It includes this functionality, in addition to all other braces (`{}`, `[]`, `<>`) and a billion other features.

Answer (score 1):

JetBrains ReSharper does this for us. However it is not free, unless your project is open source.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of pressing enter after starting a method that highlights in the IntelliSense drop-down, I just type in the `()` afterwards. That fills it in. Other keyboard strokes such as the open brace ( `[` ) key, space key, period ( `.` ) key, the open angle bracket ( `<` ) and possibly a few others I either forgot or haven't yet discovered. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the automatic brace completion feature of the [Productivity Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/d0d33361-18e2-46c0-8ff2-4adea1e34fef/).  It doesn't add the first brace, but it does add the closing brace ( **[** , **"** , **{** , **(** , etc) and you can hit <kbd>tab</kbd> after you're done and it will take you back outside of the closing brace.